# How do I run unit tests against Akka Actors using Ant?

Tags: scala, testing, ant, akka

I am in a project environment where Apache Ant is used exclusively to build, test, and deploy production application.  I do not have control or influence over this, and it will not change.  (ie. I cannot just switch to SBT for this application.)

I have inherited a Scala 2.9.3 application that I am upgrading to Scala 2.12.4.  I'm also adding SBT and IDE (Intelli-J) support for LOCAL development, build, testing purposes.

I have everything working building, testing, running locally using ANT, SBT, and the IDE.  I'm using scalatest 2.12.3 for most unit tests.  But I've run into a problem trying to integrate the Akka Test Kit : https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/testing.html

I am unable to create an Ant taskdef for running the tests.

How do I run unit tests against Akka Actors using Ant?

I can provide source code, as needed.
But I don't know how that will help, so please be specific if you want/need to see something.

Thanks!

Comment: Good question - I would like to know the answer to this as well.

Comment: I wonder if the question is in fact how you run scalatest tests from ant rather than related to the Akka? The testkit is just a regular object that you create and use inside your test framework not a test framework in itself.

Comment: Johan, I am able to run ScalaTest in ANT.
The block is that I'm unable to run the AKKA Actor tests.  I can hack some actor testing into ScalaTest, which I'll probably do if I cannot get the AKKA test kit to work as expected.  Perhaps I have a misunderstanding on how the AKKA test kit works.  I'll do more digging.  Thanks for the suggetion.